# Decimal validation in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 in my current project. I just wanted to validate my input field with decimal validation. I dont have much experience in using JQuery things. My DB decimal type field is like this (decimal(9, 2)). I wanted to validate the user against the allowed specification.

I tried using test method of jquery. But in IE8, when i fire the validation check throws not available error.

I found regular expression to do this. But i dont know which event of the textbox that i should fire the validation check. Please help me to provide the exact expression for the above said declaration.

Thanks

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090339/validate-decimal-numbers

Comment: You can use the blur event. Note that client-side validation is an optional nice-to-have,  but server-side validation is mandatory...

Comment: @Dom Can you please tell me which .js file i can get the test method

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your project and download the source from [here](http://jquery.com/download/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

then for decimal validatoin

```
$.validator.addMethod('Decimal', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d+(\.\d{0,3})?$/.test(value); 
}, "Please enter a correct number, format xxxx.xxx");
```

or with commas permitted:

```
$.validator.addMethod('Decimal', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9,]+(\.\d{0,3})?$/.test(value); 
}, "Please enter a correct number, format xxxx.xxx");
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was using externally to block the user input after specified values. `\d{0,3}` is after decimal point. I want to restrict before decimal point also. How can i do this in the above Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Heard of [Data Annotations in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) ?

Use this

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9,]+(\.\d{0,3})?$")]
public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

and then use this

```
<p>
    <label for="UnitPrice">Price:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("UnitPrice")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("UnitPrice", "*")
</p>
```